# jQuery update line total on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a section where there is 6 line items for a user to enter their class information for reimbursement. I want the user to be able to enter the cost of books and tuition and then as they tab or keyup, it will enter the total at the end of that line as well as updating the grand total for all of them.

What would be the best approach to do this with jQuery? Is change or keyup a better solution?

[image]

Comment: I'd do it on change or blur, could get kinda crazy if the calculations are firing on every key press.

Comment: I dont think it's a _which one the better_ issue. Since there are only 6 rows , `keyup` wouldnt hurt and it would be nice to see the results on every entry change inside inputs too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am suggesting that you should write blur event for "Tuition Fee" and "Books" textboxes.

Something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#Class1Tuition #Class1Book").blur(function(){
    $("#Class1Total").val(parseInt($("#Class1Tuition").val()) + parseInt($("#Class1Book").val()));
    CalculateGrandTotal();  //It will calculate the grand total and fill into textboxt. You should create this function
  });
});
```

Comment: Would there be any reason it isnt accepting 2 ids for my selector ?

Comment: This is a bad idea, as you'll have to copy/paste that code over and over for each ID.  Much better to use classes and attach the event handlers better on that, better still to use on() as in my example.

Comment: The callback function itself (besides still relying on IDs) is solid though.

Comment: Yeah, you can do the same thing using the class name also.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of situation is exactly what [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) was designed for.  Read up on that page for more details, but basically you can attach a single event listener to the parent element of all the boxes that will listen for events from all of them, instead of attaching a bunch of listeners to every box.  Without actual code, I'm just making assumptions about the structure of your code, but here's an example:

```
$('#ClassDetails').on('blur','input.books input.fees',function(evt) {
    $currow = $(this).closest('tr');
    $currow.find('.total').val(parseInt($currow.find('.fees').val()) + parseInt($currow.find('.books').val()))
    CalculateGrandTotal();
});
```

This will be much more efficient, faster, and less taxing than attaching an event listener to every element, and is much nicer to work with imo.

As a bonus, if you want to listen to multiple events (blur and keyup, say), you can do so by simply specifying multiple space-delimited events, like so:

```
$('#ClassDetails').on('blur keyup','input.books input.fees',function(evt) {
```

If you're doing that, consider checking the keycode (`evt.which`) and only doing processing on that.  You probably want to do some checking unless you want to be summing up partial numbers (adding 1 before 15 before 150 to the total).

Another thing you might consider adding, depending on how many fields you're working with and how fast things are as-is, is instead of getting the values of each element you need every update, just mirror the values in a JSON object, update the value that changed in that object, and then run the totals on that.  That would be more complex, but also a bit faster than accessing the values directly.

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZAL6X/) I put together for a different person with a similar question.  It uses sliders instead of text boxes for input, but the basics are the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you could indeed do with jquery by binding keyevents to updating the calculated values you need. Another option however would be to use a framework that makes data-binding much more easier. Personally I like the AngularJS framework, but there are other's out there that are probably more suited to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe onkeyup would be not recomendable but always this depends on client requeriments and the behavior you want.

OnChange and onblur have similar behavior at least on chrome, but on keydown or keyup you have real time calculation, so what you use depends of what you want.

Check this fidle http://jsfiddle.net/ghtep/

```
   $(function(){
        $("#group1 .test").change(function(){
            var result = 0;
            $("#group1 .test").each(function(){ result += Number($(this).val()); })
            $("#group1 .result").val(result);
        });

   $("#group2 .test").blur(function(){
        var result = 0;
        $("#group2 .test").each(function(){ result += Number($(this).val()); })
        $("#group2 .result").val(result);
    });

    $("#group3 .test").keyup(function(){
        var result = 0;
        $("#group3 .test").each(function(){ result += Number($(this).val()); })
        $("#group3 .result").val(result);
    });
});
```